# How can I solve this in jsp?

Tags: css, html, forms, jsp

help me with the Jsp code of a page which has a form of editing the user details once he logs in into his account, the page must have the users image on top right side and the form must be in the center.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. If you haven't tried anything, then I suggest maybe looking for JSP tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
 <div class="main" style="clear:both;float: left;width:100%;" >
            <div class="topRight" style="width:100%;float: left;" align="right">
                <img src="images/pic.jpg" height="30" width="auto"><p>Jane <a href="#">LogOut</a></p>

            </div>
            <div class="content" style="width:100%;float: left;" align="center">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="un" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="submit"  value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset">

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
```

If you want to get the image dynamically you can just assign the path to a String and then set the variable value to the src attribute in img tag

```
<img src="<%=path%>" height="30" width="auto"><p>Jane <a href="#">LogOut</a></p>
```